# In angular.js $digest does not works after making $state.go()

Tags: angularjs, digest

I have a code that makes changes in the `$scope` by making `$scope.$digest()` but when i made `$state.go();` the `$digest` won't work. Am i miss some `$state.go` parameter for this. I did not changed the controller two of the view are using the same controller.

Comment: Not much to go on here. Can you define "won't work"?  Are you seeing any error messages? (Perhaps a "digest already in progress"?)

Comment: no error it shows. i am trying it on ionic with an ipad so i can not see the errors.

Comment: Working blind is no way to work.  

Plug your iPad into a mac, and open safari on the desktop machine; in the Develop menu item you can open a dev tools console for the instance of Safari running on the iPad.

Comment: Dear Daniel i am new on ios thank you for your information. I debug it from safari but no error comes.

Comment: It would be better if you can add a plunkr codes to here.